# Unique constraints across a many to many relationship table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

**Is there any way to add a constraint to ensure that an entry of X in one column can then only allow an entry of Y in another column?**

Say I have two tables, stripped down to minimal columns, tbl_1 has a pk. tbl_2 has 2 columns - a pk and a text string.

These tables are joined by a 3rd relationship table because they're many to many and it uses pk from tbl1 and tbl2.

```
t1_pk     t2_pk | t2_str     t1fk | t2fk
  x         1       AAA        x      1
  y         2       BBB        x      2
  z         3       AAA        y      3  
            4       BBB        y      4
                               z      1
                               z      2
```

All entries above are allowed, but now I'm trying to figure out how I can constrict the relationship table so that the string attached to t2_pk can only tie in to the t1_pk ONCE. E.g. in the 3rd table:

```
 t1fk | t2fk
   x      3
```

would not be allowed because x-1 exists and both 1 and 3 have the string AAA attached. One way I can think without making 3 more tables and going round in circles, is to move the string to the relationship table and add a constraint so if the t2fk number exists in the table already it'll only allow the number again if accompanied by the same string.

**is there a background process for this I can declare like adding a unique constraint, or would it simply need to be imposed by a stored procedure?**

Comment: MySQL doesn't have any built-in constraints other than unique keys and foreign keys. For anything else, you have to use a trigger script that checks the condition.

Comment: Hmm ok. When I figured out what I needed I wondered if my design wasn't well thought out but I can't even pick a way to better represent thing unless I make a lookup table which could end up a large duplication and will rely on storedprocs to lookup anyway... felt like there might be built-in mechanism for it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It sounds very much like you're looking for a very complicated solution to a relatively simple problem.

Comment: I'm looking for a very simple solution! Just to an over-complicated problem that I can't simplify to find the simple solution.

Comment: How about putting both `t2_pk` and `t2_str` in the relation table? Then you can specify a unique constraint on `(t1_fk, t2_str)`. But this redundancy violates normalization, you'll need to implement a way to propagate changes to `t2_str` from one table to another.

Comment: FKs are quite limited in what they can do.  But anything the least bit complex in your API -- either in your app code, or in a stored proc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you add a t2_str column to your third table that contains the relations or you create a new table for this purpose. Here an example how to implement the new table tab_constr.

```
drop table if exists tab_constr;
drop table if exists tab_rel;
drop table if exists tab_1;
drop table if exists tab_2;


CREATE TABLE tab_1 (
  t1_pk varchar(5),
  PRIMARY KEY (t1_pk)
);

CREATE TABLE tab_2 (
  t2_pk INT,
  t2_str varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (t2_pk),
  INDEX(t2_pk, t2_str)
);


CREATE TABLE tab_rel (
  t1_pk varchar(5),
  t2_pk INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (t1_pk,t2_pk),
  INDEX (t2_pk),
  FOREIGN KEY (t1_pk) REFERENCES tab_1(t1_pk),
  FOREIGN KEY (t2_pk) REFERENCES tab_2(t2_pk)
);

CREATE TABLE tab_constr (
  t1_pk varchar(5),
  t2_str varchar(10),
  t2_pk int,  
  PRIMARY KEY pair_already_exists(t1_pk,t2_str),
  INDEX(t1_pk, t2_pk),
  INDEX(t2_pk, t2_str),
  FOREIGN KEY (t1_pk, t2_pk) REFERENCES tab_rel(t1_pk, t2_pk)
  ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (t2_pk, t2_str) REFERENCES tab_2(t2_pk, t2_str)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
);


CREATE TRIGGER tr_ins_rel AFTER INSERT ON tab_rel
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tab_constr ( t1_pk, t2_str, t2_pk)
        select new.t1_pk, t2_str, new.t2_pk
            from tab_2 
            where t2_pk=new.t2_pk
        ;
  END;

INSERT INTO tab_1 (t1_pk) VALUES ('x');
INSERT INTO tab_1 (t1_pk) VALUES ('y');
INSERT INTO tab_1 (t1_pk) VALUES ('z');
INSERT INTO tab_2 (t2_pk,t2_str) VALUES (1, 'AAA');
INSERT INTO tab_2 (t2_pk,t2_str) VALUES (2, 'BBB');
INSERT INTO tab_2 (t2_pk,t2_str) VALUES (3, 'AAA');
INSERT INTO tab_2 (t2_pk,t2_str) VALUES (4, 'BBB');
INSERT INTO tab_rel (t1_pk,t2_pk) VALUES ('x', 1);
INSERT INTO tab_rel (t1_pk,t2_pk) VALUES ('x', 2);
INSERT INTO tab_rel (t1_pk,t2_pk) VALUES ('y', 3);
INSERT INTO tab_rel (t1_pk,t2_pk) VALUES ('y', 4);
INSERT INTO tab_rel (t1_pk,t2_pk) VALUES ('z', 1);
INSERT INTO tab_rel (t1_pk,t2_pk) VALUES ('z', 2);
commit;
```

The following statement will raise an error:

```
INSERT INTO tab_rel (t1_pk,t2_pk) VALUES ('x', 3);
```

This also raises an error

```
UPDATE tab_2 set t2_str='BBB' where t2_pk=1;
```

But this will work

```
DELETE FROM tab_rel where t1_pk='x' and t2_pk=1;
INSERT INTO tab_rel (t1_pk,t2_pk) VALUES ('x', 3);
```

and this will work

```
UPDATE tab_2 set t2_str='XXX' where t2_pk=1;
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/FMFYB53933) you can try it out.

Of course this additional table violates normal form and adds redundancy to your database. But that is no problem because this table tab_constr is an auxiliary structure like an index and it will be automatically maintained by the database. So no insert/update/delete anomalies will occur.

Comment: Hi, this is great stuff, I don't even understand a lot of it, but I'll put this as the accepted answer and go through this properly when I get back to work. Thanks very much for your time here.